# Tomcat 8.5 would not start on Windows Server 2012

Tags: tomcat

I just deployed (i.e. using the ZIP version of the download) Apache Tomcat 8.5 into a Windows Server 2012. Following are the steps taken:

1. Unzip into a special folder (not within the "C:" but somewhere else),
2. Defined the SYSTEM-LEVEL environment variable CATALINA_HOME pointing to the root of the deployment (e.g. `K:\My Software\apache-tomcat-8.5.11`),
3. Made sure that JAVA_HOME points to the correct folder (in my case it would be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_66`),

I then opened a command window, went to the `bin` folder and executed the command `startup.bat`, which caused another window to appear for a fraction of a second and then... nothing. Also tried as Administrator but with the same result.

My recollection is that it takes few seconds for Tomcat to be ready, time during which the temporary window is visible and a number of lines are written. In my case, it is like an eye blink.

I can't find error logs or any other indication that would explain why it is not working (which I checked by entering `http:\\localhost:8080` into the browser).

Where can I find evidences of the issue (and perhaps add whatever I find to this question for further support)?

Answer (score 0):

I think JAVA_HOME must be the jdk installed path and JRE_HOME must be the jre installed path..Also you have to set CATALINA_HOME.In path variable add a new variable value as ;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin;Go through http://doraprojects.net/blog/?p=1109

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have not both JDK and JRE installed, variables set (JRE_HOME, JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME) and still the DOS window flashes for a fraction of a second and vanishes. Is there a way to see any logs with the reason of the failure?

Comment: @FDavidov Do you have sufficient privileges(Admin privilege) to start the service? if yes, try the following restart computer,
change tomcat port,
close every unnecessary applications: skype, ip phones etc

Comment: Restarted the machine, changed port to 9090, and still no use. What appears strange from your words is "starting the service": The link you sent (as well as my installation) are not creating any service. I traced the BAT files execution (`catalina.bat` and `setclasspath.bat`) and they appear to end successfully. Still, the window flashes and goes away.

Comment: One more things: I tried to create a service (using the batch file `service.bat`) but it did not create any service (it completes with an error message about its failure).